# Traverse n-level parent child list C#

Tags: list, parent-child, traversal

I have a parent-child list. It can be of n-level.

I need each item within this hierarchy.

I am using 'foreach' loop and recursive function but it's not working.

I have went through other solutions at 'stackoverflow' but none of them worked for me.

```
public class Item
  {
    public int  Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    private List<Item> children = new List<Item>();

    public List<Item> Children
    {
        get { return children; }
        set { children = value; }
    }

}

   List<Item> test = new List<Item>();
            test.Add(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Root1", ParentId = -1 });
            test[0].Children.Add(new Item { Id = 4, Name = "child-1-Root1", ParentId = 1 });
            test[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new Item { Id = 10, Name = "grandchild-1-Root1", ParentId = 4 });
            test[0].Children.Add(new Item { Id = 5, Name = "child-2-Root1", ParentId = 1 });

            test.Add(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Root2", ParentId = -1 });
            test[1].Children.Add(new Item { Id = 6, Name = "child-1-Root2", ParentId = 2 });
            test[1].Children.Add(new Item { Id = 7, Name = "child-2-Root2", ParentId = 2 });

            test.Add(new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Root3", ParentId = -1 });
            test[2].Children.Add(new Item { Id = 8, Name = "child-1-Root3", ParentId = 3 });
            test[2].Children.Add(new Item { Id = 9, Name = "child-2-Root3", ParentId = 3 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
public static Find()
{
     foreach (var item in test)
      {
                FindRecursively(item, item.Name);
      }
}

 public static Item FindRecursively(Item node, string name)
        {
            if (node == null)
                return null;

            if (node.Name == name)
                Console.WriteLine(node.Name);

            foreach (var child in node.Children)
            {
                var found = FindRecursively(child, child.Name);

            }

            return null;
        }
```